# Passing a variable into PHPMailer body

Tags: php

I am using PHPMailer to send emails after registration, but I can't seem to put a variable into

```
$htmlBody = '<html><body><a href = "http://www.mywebsite.com/confirm_registration.php?passkey={$com_code}">Confirm</a></body></html>';
```

Where $com_code is a unique passkey attached to a link received by the user in their email. The problem is that $com_code is showing up as $com_code instead of the actual string. Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes for the string, and escape the double quotes inside, as such:

```
$htmlBody = "<html><body><a href=\"http://www.mywebsite.com/confirm_registration.php?passkey={$com_code}\">Confirm</a></body></html>";
```

Alternatively, use the concatenation operator instead, as such:

```
$htmlBody = '<html><body><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/confirm_registration.php?passkey=' . $com_code . '">Confirm</a></body></html>';
```

PHP only searches for variables inside strings wrapped with double quotes.

Comment: That is good to know. It will save me a lot of headaches in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with the PHPMailer. The problem is you are attempting to interpolate a variable in the string wrongly. 
Remember that unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.
You can use two ways out of many in your situation:

1)

```
$htmlBody = "<html><body><a href = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/confirm_registration.php?passkey={$com_code}'>Confirm</a></body></html>";
```

2)

```
$htmlBody = '<html><body><a href = "http://www.mywebsite.com/confirm_registration.php?passkey='.$com_code.'">Confirm</a></body></html>';
```

Please note how quotes are used!